# .net core on linux hosting issue in css and other static file

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I am new in linux hosting.
I want to host my .net core app on azure ubuntu 16.0 hosting.
by following some articles i get success in deployment, but the site is not loading css,js & images in other words we can say it not loading any static files.

here is IP of my site : http://13.85.26.168/

Comment: Have you see the publish folder contains following files ![](https://ws2.sinaimg.cn/large/006tKfTcgy1fitosezhzoj31kw060wii.jpg)

Comment: yes all files are there, and in wwwroot folder

Comment: even if we try to load other pages like about or contact us it gives us 404 error.

Comment: Is the `css` and `js`  path alright? even the case. For Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: yes all path are alright

Comment: deploy again still having same issue. new url : http://13.85.26.168/

Comment: I assume it works locally? Are you sure that `app.UseStaticFiles();` is being called even in production?

Comment: Now it solved, I follow two links                                                                         
This two links are very useful, follow first one and 2 for installing .net core
https://www.meziantou.net/2017/04/25/publishing-an-asp-net-core-website-to-a-linux-host
https://pioneercode.com/post/developing-a-net-core-site-in-windows-and-deploying-it-to-a-budget-linux-host

Answer (score 0):

Now it solved, I follow two links
This two links are very useful, follow first one and 2 for installing .net core

https://www.meziantou.net/2017/04/25/publishing-an-asp-net-core-website-to-a-linux-host
https://pioneercode.com/post/developing-a-net-core-site-in-windows-and-deploying-it-to-a-budget-linux-host

Make sure you read all steps and understand and then follow.

Thanks